# Questions app without repetition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make a question app which shows a random question from a plist I made. This is the function (there are only 7 questions for now).

My function gives a random question but it always starts with the same question
and a question can be repeated. I need your help to generate the question randomly and without repetition.

```
 currentQuestion=rand()%7;
 NSDictionary *nextQuestion = [self.questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];

    self.answer = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"questionAnswer"];

    self.qlabel.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"questionTitle"];

    self.lanswer1.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"A"];

    self.lanswer2.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"B"];

    self.lanswer3.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"C"];

    self.lanswer4.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"D"];
```

Comment: Hey Eyasin, I didn't get you, why do you want me to edit your code?

Answer (score 2):

`rand()%7;` will always produces a unique sequence of random numbers.

Use `arc4random() % 7;` instead.

```
currentQuestion=arc4random() %7;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way (in ARC, written out extra long for clarity):

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *unaskedQuestions;

- (NSString *)nextRandomUnaskedQuestion {

    if (!self.unaskedQuestions) {
        // using your var name 'nextQuestion'.  consider renaming it to 'questions'
        self.unaskedQuestions = [nextQuestion mutableCopy];
    }

    if ([self.unaskedQuestions count] == 0) return nil;  // we asked everything

    NSArray *keys = [self.unaskedQuestions allKeys];
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [allKeys count];
    NSString *randomKey = [keys objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    NSString *nextRandomUnaskedQuestion = [self.unaskedQuestions valueForKey:randomKey];

    [self.unaskedQuestions removeObjectForKey:randomKey];
    return nextRandomUnaskedQuestion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an array of your question keys. Say you have array named arrKeys --> [A], [B], [C], [D], ... , [z], nil
2. Use (arc4random() % array.length-1) {as suggested by Suresh} to generate rendom index for your array. Say you got rand = 3
3. Get the key from array arrKeys @3 = D. Then from your NSDictionary use [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"D"] and also remove the 'D' key from your array as [arrKeys removeObjectAtIndex:3]. Repeat 1-3 steps for next question.

Comment: suresh: thnx 4 replaying you helped me.with the sequence thing but still not unique numbers

Comment: mann: i rly dont have much experience in objective c can u help writing the code u explained

Comment: refer @danh's answer below. That's what you are looking for.